# Kendo Grid clicked row count

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

How can I exclude group names while calculating the clicked row count in a Kendo grid?

I have 10 data in a grid under 3 groups. If I click on the last row it returns count as `12`. I'm using the below code.

```
var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index($(this).closest('tr'));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Below code works.

```
    var grid = $("#daGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataRows = grid.items();
    var uid = grid.select()[0].dataset.uid
    var documentItems = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    var tr = $("[data-uid='" + uid + "']", grid.tbody);
    var rowIndex = dataRows.index(grid.select());
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? There might be a different way to go about it. For example, $('#gridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total() would give you 10.

**Update**

This code will get you the selected row number in the case only one row is selected:

```
let selectedRows = $('#gridName').data('kendoGrid').select()
selectedRows[0].rowIndex
```

Comment: I need to calculate the selected row number.